# Large Integer Division - Knuth's Algorithm D

Tags: c++, integer-division

I have to divide any number (no matter the size) by another number using Large Integer Division using Knuth's Algorithm D (The art of programming Volume 2), for example `74839234` by `72548`.

I made two arrays to represent these numbers

```
n[] = {7,4,8,3,9,2,3,4}
d[] = {7,2,5,4,8}
```

I am trying to get an output like this:

```
q[] = {1,0,3,1}
r[] = {4,2,2,4,6}
```

I really don't know where to start with this. Any help or guidance would be appreciated!

Comment: Write the algorithm you have been instructed to use in english instructions, e.g. how you would tell a human to do it. Identify programming structures like for loops and ifs and whiles in it. Rewrite as pseudocode. Then, rewrite it as code.

Comment: which programming language ?

Comment: Im having some issues understanding the algorithm. Because of that i dont know where to start when pseudocode. I have been sitting playing in excel trying to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

At D1 you have `d=1`, so set

```
n[]={0,7,4,8,3,9,2,3,4}
```

`n = 5`, `m = 3`.

Also, there is a formal error in step D4: (second line) should be ...

`minus q(hat) times (v1, v2, ..., vn)b TIMES b ** (m - j)`.

Here, ** means "power of" (Fortran style for easy writing). Of course, `b = 10` here, so

`times b ** (m - j)` shifts the subtrahend left, to proper place for subtraction.